# Why Green's equation sign changes in some problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, greens-function

In some textbooks I have seen the Green's equation in this way:
$$ L G(x,s) = \delta(x - s)$$
But in some other.
$$ L G(x,s) = -\delta(x - s)$$

In Wikipedia, they say the change in sign is used in physical problems, but don't give a reason for this. May some one give me a reason about it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some problems in physics, the operator $\mathscr{L}$ operates on a object to yield the negative of another object.

For example, in electrostatics, we have $\mathscr{L}=\nabla^2$ that operates on the electrostatic potential $\Phi(\vec r)$ and yields the negative of the volume charge density $\rho(\vec r)$ divided by the permittivity of free space.  That is to say,

$$\nabla^2 \Phi(\vec r)=-\frac{\rho(\vec r)}{\epsilon} \tag 1$$

with suitable boundary conditions given to provide a well-posed problem (e.g., Dirichlet or Neumann boundary conditions).

Then, if the Green's Function $G(\vec r|\vec r')$ is the solution of

$$\nabla^2 G(\vec r|\vec r')=-\delta(\vec r-\vec r')$$

then the solution to $(1)$ for the free-space problem (i.e., unbounded problem) is

$$\Phi(\vec r)=\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{R^3}\rho(\vec r')\,G(\vec r|\vec r')\,dV' \tag 2$$

which avoids the use of the minus sign on the right-hand side of $(2)$.

And that is about all there is to the rationale for the convention.

Comment: Great explanation Dr. MV, thanks a lot

Comment: @JuanCamiloAcostaArango Wow.  Thank you for this nice comment.  And you're certainly welcome.  It was really my pleasure!